# What is the most efficient way to compute sum of sum of divisors of all numbers from 1 to n?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, sieve-theory

​​$σ_1(i)$ be the sum of divisors of $i$,

Calculate

​$S(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n σ_1(i)$

I am looking for something better than $O(\sqrt{n})$

To address @ingix's question here is my  $O(\sqrt{n})$ python code:
The beauty of this approach  is you dont need to know $σ_1(i)$ for each i, you just need to have all their ingredients in the final sum.

```
# http://oeis.org/A024916

def triangular(n):
    return n * (n + 1) // 2

def A024916(n):
    sum = 0
    up = 0
    i = 1
    while i * i < n:
        now = n // i
        before = n // (i + 1)
        # trick = http://oeis.org/A257212
        sum += i * (triangular(now) - triangular(before))
        up = before
        i += 1
    for i in range(1, up + 1):
        sum += n // i * i
    return sum


n = int(input())
if n <= 2:
    print([1, 4][n - 1])
else:
    print(A024916(n))
```

EDIT:
I found a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.3369.pdf) which does it in  $O(n^{1/3})$ .
Will update once I understand it properly.

Mean while if someone has a better or similar approach you are welcome.

Comment: Are you sure that you know an algorithm that works in $O(\sqrt{n})$ for $S(n)$? For $\sigma_1(n)$ that's easy, but you have to calculate many of those values to get $S(n)$, so the times add up!

Comment: Is this helpful: [A024916  a(n) = Sum_{k=1..n} k*floor(n/k); also Sum_{k=1..n} sigma(k) where sigma(n) = sum of divisors of n (A000203).](https://oeis.org/A024916)

Comment: @Ingix updated with my $O(\sqrt{n})$ code. I am sure it can be done better possibly by using bitwise sieve or something similar.

Comment: May it be assumed that $n$ is small enough so that whichever computer that you are running the algorithm on can handle a two dimensional array, where one dimension is $(n)$, and the other dimension is the exact number of prime numbers $\leq n$ ?  If $n$ may be assumed small enough, then I may be able to improve on your approach.  If not, then I can't.

Comment: @user2661923 sorry I need for n = any 64 bit integer

Answer (score 1):

By [Dirichlet's hyperbola method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_hyperbola_method), we have
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k\le n}\sigma(k)
&=\sum_{mt\le n}t=\sum_{m\le\sqrt n}\sum_{t\le n/m}t+\sum_{t\le\sqrt n}t\sum_{m\le n/t}1-\sum_{m\le\sqrt n}\sum_{t\le\sqrt n}t \\
&=\sum_{m\le\sqrt n}\frac12\left\lfloor\frac nm\right\rfloor\left(1+\left\lfloor\frac nm\right\rfloor\right)+\sum_{t\le\sqrt n}t\left\lfloor\frac nt\right\rfloor-\frac12\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor^2(1+\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor).
\end{aligned}

Combining all terms, we get
$$
\sum_{k\le n}\sigma(k)=\sum_{m\le\sqrt n}\frac12\left\lfloor\frac nm\right\rfloor\left(2m+1+\left\lfloor\frac nm\right\rfloor\right)-\frac12\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor^2(1+\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor),
$$
and from the sigma notation we see that this can also be used to create an $O(\sqrt n)$ algorithm.